# How to include a Surv object as a new column in a data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, survival

I'm performing survival analysis, and I want to create a `Surv` object as its own column in a `data.table`. Although `Surv` objects are considered vectors, I can't use them to make new column since they are actually a 2 column matrix. Is there an elegant way to include `Surv` objects without splitting them into separate columns?

This is what a `Surv` object looks like.

```r
DT[,Surv(time, status)]
#>  [1]   9   13   13+  18   23   28+  31   34   45+  48  161+   5    5    8 
#> [15]   8   12   16+  23   27   30   33   43   45
```

Here is an example of what I want to do:

```r
library(data.table)
library(survival)

DF <- as.data.frame(survival::aml)
DT <- as.data.table(survival::aml)

# Does work
DF$survival <- Surv(DF$time, DF$status)

# Does not work
DT[,survival:=Surv(time, status)]
```

Comment: there's an outstanding issue to do exactly this on the GitHub page. I spent a few minutes trying to fix the issue but couldn't track down whats going on.

Comment: Sounds like an X-Y problem, i.e., "I want to do X by way of Y (which is not allowed by syntax constraints)". So why not tell us what you want to do rather than telling us how to do it?

Comment: @42- Tell me if this makes things more clear.  Why can I store a `Surv` object as a vector in a data.frame but I cannot do the same in a data.table? Is this impossible? If not, is there a syntax nuance I'm missing that makes it work?

Comment: Dataframes accept matrices. Datatables do not.

Comment: @42- Can you please be more helpful? I'm split between bench work and bioinformatics, and I'm too tired to figure out how I was supposed to ask that question.

Comment: Describe the problem. It’s not clear that you actually need to create a Surv object inside a data.tabble.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with the `data.table` syntax, as stated by the other commenters. But as you can create a `data.frame` from the object, a very quick-and-dirty solution would be `DT <- as.data.frame(survival::aml); setDT(DT)`.

Comment: @42- Thanks! I'm trying to validate genes we think are prognostic in ovarian cancer using datasets from the Gene Expression Omnibus (GEO) (I'm aware of `curatedOvarianData` from Bioconductor).  I have collected dozens of datasets and created a suite of functions for analyzing them over the past several months.  I wanted to include the `Surv` object in the data.table to consolidate the size of the datasets and skip an analysis step. Although I could find a different solution, I was surprised that I couldn't and figured this would be a good time to understand why it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not yet clear what the underlying plan is for such a construction, but if the hope is to do survival modeling inside the data.table environment then separate construction of a `Surv`-object is not necessary. One should get comfortable with putting in complete expressions in the data.table `j`-position:

```
> DT[ , coxph( Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data=.SD) ]
Call:  coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = .SD)

Null model
  log likelihood= -42.72484 
  n= 23
```

The data.table function creates an environment where column names get evaluated  without quotes:

```
> DT[ , summary(coxph( Surv(time, status) ~ x), data=.SD) ]
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ x)

  n= 23, number of events= 18 

                 coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z Pr(>|z|)  
xNonmaintained 0.9155    2.4981   0.5119 1.788   0.0737 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

               exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
xNonmaintained     2.498     0.4003    0.9159     6.813

Concordance= 0.619  (se = 0.063 )
Likelihood ratio test= 3.38  on 1 df,   p=0.07
Wald test            = 3.2  on 1 df,   p=0.07
Score (logrank) test = 3.42  on 1 df,   p=0.06
```

In fact the practice of separate construction of `Surv`-objects outside of the coxph function is something that brings questions to the rhelp mailing list because such outside makes an object whose environment is not the dataframe offered to `coxph` but is rather the `globalenv()`. Terry Therneau, the author of the survival package, warns people NOT to make separate `Surv`-objects. This is entirely separate from any issues regarding encapsulation of matrices in data.table, but hopefully it will reduce the level of frustration with this barrier.